# (Predicate Logic) ∀x ∈ N(x > 1 → ∃k ∈ N∃m ∈ N(m ≡ 1(mod 2) ∧ x = 2^k⋅m))

Tags: predicate-logic

Can anyone show me how to prove this statement? I'm very confused.
I have tried substitute numbers into each x, k and m, it seems this statement is true but it needs to be proved by mathematical methods.

Thank you!

Comment: If $x$ is *even*, then $x=2^k$ for some $k$. Thus $x=(2n+1)2^k$ for $n=0$ and $m=2\times 0+1=1$ is *odd*.

Comment: If $x$ is *odd*, then $x=2n+1$ for some $n$, and thus $x=(2n+1) \times 2^0$.

Comment: Thus, cooking them together: $\exists k \ \exists n \ [x=(2n+1)2^k]$.

Comment: Please include a full statement of the problem you want help with in the body of the Question.  Putting the problem statement only in the title often short-changes your Readers by being cryptic.